# How can I effectively build a sentiment model training dataset using Stanford CoreNLP?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I’m interested in training a new sentiment model with my own dataset.  I know that I need to create a file with sentiment labeled for sentences and their component phrases and words.

I figured out how to create a tree like the following for the sentence “I do not love you.” via the BuildBinarizedDataset:

```
(1 (1 I) (1 (1 (1 (1 do) (1 not)) (1 (1 love) (1 you))) (1 .)))
```

However, this seems terribly difficult to add labels manually in this format, particularly for phrases within a longer sentence.  It would be far easier if I could generate the following for labeling purposes, then convert when I am ready to train the new model.

```
sentiment_score pline1

sentiment_score  phrase1

sentiment_score  phrase2

...........................

sentiment_score  phraseN

BLANK ROW

sentiment_score pline2
```

The problem is that I can’t figure out how to generate this from a sentence with the parser.  If someone could provide guidance, or direct me to documentation that will explain this process, it would help me tremendously.

Comment: You cannot _generate_ labels for your Training dataset, you have to provide it manually in order to `train` your model accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code I wrote to go through a tree and print out every subtree.  So to get the print out you want just use the printSubTrees method I wrote and have it print out everything in your sentiment tree.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Word;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.TreeBinarizer;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SubTreesExample {

    public static void printSubTrees(Tree inputTree) {
        ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
        for (Tree leaf : inputTree.getLeaves()) {
            words.addAll(leaf.yieldWords());
        }
        System.out.print(inputTree.label()+"\t");
        for (Word w : words) {
            System.out.print(w.word()+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (Tree subTree : inputTree.children()) {
            printSubTrees(subTree);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        String text = "I do not love you.";
        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        Tree sentenceTree = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0).get(
                TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
        printSubTrees(sentenceTree);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! It compiled beautifully using the Stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar but I have not been able to run it. Can you tell me what this means?

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
...

Comment: ...
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       ... 7 more

Comment: How are you running the code?  It seems like you are having some sort of CLASSPATH issue.

Comment: I am in the folder that contains the java, class and the jar file.
I’ve tried running different combination of the example below.
Example:  java –cp “Stanford-corenlp3.6.0.jar” –classpath .  SubTreesExample

Comment: If you are in the main distribution folder with all of the jars, you should run java -cp "*:." ...you need all of the jars and you need the compiled SubTreesExample in your CLASSPATH

Comment: Ok it worked for us with:
`java -cp *;.`

Returned:

`ROOT I do not love you .
S I do not love you .
NP I
PRP I
I-1 I
VP do not love you
VBP do
do-2 do
RB not
not-3 not
VP love you
VB love
love-4 love
NP you
PRP you
you-5 you
. .
.-6 .`

Is there a short list of parts of speech that we need to retain and label for training?  (E.g. NP, VP, etc.)  We don’t need all of these, right?

Comment: We're really close... RESULT: `(2 (2 (2 In) (2 (2 a) (2 way))) (2 (2 ,) (2 (2 (2 the) (2 film)) (2 (2 (2 feels) (2 (2 (2 (2 (2 (2 like) (2 (2 (2 a) (2 breath)) (2 (2 of) (2 (2 fresh) (2 air))))) (2 ,)) (2 but)) (2 only)) (2 (2 to) (2 (2 those) (2 (2 that) (2 (2 (2 allow) (2 it)) (2 in))))))) (2 .)))))`  STANFORD TREE: `(2 (2 (2 In) (2 (2 a) (2 way))) (2 (2 ,) (2 (2 (2 the) (2 film)) (2 (2 (2 feels) (2 (2 (2 like) (2 (2 (2 a) (2 breath)) (2 (2 of) (2 (2 fresh) (2 air))))) (2 (2 ,) (2 (2 but) (2 (2 only) (2 (2 to) (2 (2 those) (2 (2 that) (2 (2 (2 allow) (2 it)) (2 in)))))))))) (2 .)))))`

Comment: The above is a test I did, to compare our results to the way the trees are formatted in the movie review sentiment dataset.  As you can see, it's really close, but not exactly the same.

Comment: My example just showed how to go through a Tree.  You should supply it with the binary Tree you are building with numeric labels.